# Android Studio Log Cat continuously Shows data

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have searched this issue in SO, but those answers did not help me.

I have recently updated my Android SDK in Android Studio. After that whenever I connect my device via USB, it shows whole data from Android Device in the Logcat. I thought of filtering it by selecting Debug, Verbose and error according to the usage. But still there is unnecessary data in everything. In previous SDK, I did not see this problem. How to solve avoid unnecessary data?

[image: SnapShot]

Comment: put a snapshot along with applied filter (only of your logcat view don't include entire studio view )

Comment: Added snapshot. Data is not stopping.

Answer (score 1):

The `show only selected application` filter only works if you have an application selected. In the toolbar above it `no debuggable applications` indicates it did not find any application to filter so it simply shows the entire logcat output.

Build and deploy an application to the device and then select the application from the dropdown many that now says `no debuggable applications`. The output should then be filtered to only your application.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I saw that `no debuggable applications`. But whenever I connect device it is not automatically finding the device.

Comment: I got it working. I have to enable `ADB integration` in Tools>Android> Enable ADB Integration

Answer (score 0):

Choose the Log level to waring or error, and in your code use

```
    log.w("TAG", "Warning log message");
```

or

```
 log.e("TAG", "Error log message");
```

If you want to use the debug log level, you can use

```
log.d("MYDEBUGTAG", "Debugg log message");
```

and filter the debugging messages by typing your tag "MYDEBUGTAG" on the textbox next to the log level selector.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry not helpful, I tired all that.